# Twitter API V2 reply to a tweet (getting 403 (unsupported authentication) with bearer token)

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, twitter-api-v2

getting these error

```
Error Part


{
    "title": "Unsupported Authentication",
    "detail": "Authenticating with OAuth 2.0 Application-Only is forbidden for this endpoint.  Supported authentication types are [OAuth 1.0a User Context, OAuth 2.0 User Context].",
    "type": "https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/unsupported-authentication",
    "status": 403
}


const { TwitterApi } = require("twitter-api-v2");
const config = require("../../config");
const client = new TwitterApi({
  appKey: config.twitter_config.api_key,
  appSecret: config.twitter_config.api_secret,
  accessToken: config.twitter_config.access_token,
  accessSecret: config.twitter_config.access_secret,
});
const bearer = new TwitterApi(process.env.BEARER_TOKEN);
const twitterClient = client.readWrite;
const twitterBearer = bearer.readOnly;
module.exports = { twitterClient, twitterBearer };



// i tried with these 2 methods 




async function replyToTweet(tweetId, replyMessage,accesstoken) {
            const accessToken =accesstoken ; 
            const url = `https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets`;
            const headers = {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            };
            const data = {
              hidden: false,
              in_reply_to_user_id: tweetId,
              status: replyMessage,
            };
            try {
              const response =await axios.post(url,{
                tweet:{
                    in_reply_to_status_id:tweetId,
                    text:replyMessage,
                }
              },{headers});
              console.log('Reply sent successfully:', response);
            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error replying to tweet:', error);
            }
          }



   async function replyToTweet() {
                try {
                  const tweet = await client.v1.tweets.reply(tweetId, {
                    status: "maggi reply",
                  });
                  console.log('Reply sent successfully:', tweet.text);
                } catch (error) {
                  console.error('Error replying to tweet:', error);
                }
              }
```

I am trying hard to find a way to reply to a tweet with Twitter API V2, but it seems there is no endpoint for doing something like that, in Twitter API V2 package i found a way to a tweet, but i am struggling with replies, can you please help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to abandoning the wrapper package and using Axios instead:

```
try {
 res = axios({
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    Accept: "application/json",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  },
  data: {
    text: options.body,
  },
  url: "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets",
})
} catch(error) {
   console.errror(error)
}
```